# How can I create a subplot from for loop with an if statement or using any other suitable method

Tags: matlab, for-loop, if-statement, subplot

I have two threshold values (scalars) that I would like to run through my for loop, and subsequently plot each 'meanMUA' (for that particular threshold value)  as a subplot.

I attempted the following, but the 'meanMUA' for threshold1 is subplotted in both specified positions, rather than the 'meanMUA' for threshold1 (in position 1) and threshold2 (in position 2):

```
threshold1 = 0.018; 
threshold2 = 2*threshold1;

figure;
for threshold = 1:2
    
    for trial = 1:50

        for channel = 1:16

            for bin = 1:10000

                %%access data from bins, using sliding window
                bindata = absData(((bin*binWidth)+1-binWidth : bin*binWidth), channel, trial);

                if threshold == threshold1 || threshold == threshold2

                    %%calculate mua above threshold
                    mua(bin, channel, trial) = sum(bindata >= threshold);

                end

            end

        end

    end
    
meanMUA = (mean(mua,3)).';

subplot(1,2, threshold);
clims=[0 1];
imagesc(meanMUA,clims)
 
end
```

I have attempted other variations of this code, including re-structuring the if/elseif statement and calculating the meanMUA for both thresholds within the if/elseif statement, though this doesn't work either:

```
if threshold == threshold1

        %%calculate mua above threshold
        mua(bin, channel, trial) = sum(bindata >= threshold);
        meanMUA = (mean(mua,3)).';
        
        subplot(1,2, threshold);
        clims=[0 1];
        imagesc(meanMUA,clims)

     elseif threshold == threshold2

        %%calculate mua above threshold
        mua(bin, channel, trial) = sum(bindata >= threshold);
        meanMUA = (mean(mua,3)).';
        
        subplot(1,2, threshold);
        clims=[0 1];
        imagesc(meanMUA,clims)
        
end
```

Does anyone know how I can solve this? Your help is appreciated.

I am using Matlab 2019b.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first for loop, `for threshold = 1:2` means `threshold` can only take the values 1 and 2. It would never be equal to `threshold1 = 0.018` and `threshold2 = 2*threshold1 = 0.036`.

One solution would be to define the two thresholds in a vector: `thresholds = [0.018, 2*0.018]`. Then in the for loop:

```
for t = 1:2
    ...
    %%access data from bins, using sliding window
    bindata = absData(((bin*binWidth)+1-binWidth : bin*binWidth), channel, trial)

    %%calculate mua above threshold
    mua(bin, channel, trial) = sum(bindata >= thresholds(t));
    ...
end
```

This will provide values with the bindata thresholded at threshold1 and threshold2.